# Displaying more than 100 entries in Relation Reference Widget dropdown in QGIS

Tags: qgis, relation, qgis-widget

I am using QGIS 3.28, and I've encountered an issue with the Relation Reference Widget. In the form view, the dropdown menu of the Relation Reference Widget only displays 100 entries.

Is there a way to increase the number of entries displayed in the dropdown menu?

I've tried looking for an option in the widget settings, but I couldn't find any way to modify the maximum number of displayed entries.

Comment: Would you be open to using the 'Use completer' option as that's how I've gotten around it (often lists with >100 entries are unwieldly from an UI perspective anyway). Edit - that's in relation to Value Relation though, I assume Relation Reference works the same but haven't ever really used it to be honest.

Comment: The Relation Reference don't have the option for "use completer"